# Stage waits indefinitely in "Waiting in the Deployment Queue" state

Tags: azure-devops

I have a stage that waits indefinitely (17 hours +) in "Waiting in the Deployment Queue" state. Other stages can be deployed and are assigned a job within 1 minute.

Why might a Stage not be assigned a job? What affects the priority of assigning a job to a Stage?

Answer (score 2):

By default, when you add a stage in release pipeline, the `Maximum number of parallel deployments` is 1.

[image]

This means that you can only run release deployment one by one.

When you see the state:Waiting in the Deployment Queue, there should be unfinished deployment before this deployment.

As you said, we could click the **view queue** option to check the inprocess deployment and cacel or reject it.

[image]

The order of its deployment is time from front to back.

In order to avoid this kind of stuck situation, you can also try to increase Maximum number of parallel deployments to 2 or a larger number.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the logs for the Stage
There is a View Queue link. Go there.
It lists what the job is waiting on starting at the bottom of the list.
Click on the release to navigate to the Stage and release or reject the Stage as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into something that sounds similar. I had approvals enabled on the stage, and it defaults to needing approval in sequence from all assigned approvers. There is a radial button for Approval order. Set it to "Any one user". You'll have to cancel the current release, but you can redeploy that specific stage, on that specific release.